# GoDaddy php mail() will not submit

Tags: php

For starters, I don't use StackOverflow very often, so please, bear with me.

Anyway, I am working with a client to build a simple PHP contact form. The problem is that it is not submitting. Is there something that is missing? We are currently using GoDaddy for hosting.

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Surname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send Message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</form> 


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $headers = "From: ".$_POST['email']."" . "\r\n";
    //$body = $_POST['name']."<br>".$_POST['surname']."<br>".$_POST['message']."<br>"; 
    $body = $_POST['name']."<br>".$_POST['surname']."<br>".$_POST['message']."<br>"; 
    mail("xxxx@gmail.com", "New Inquiry", $body, $headers);
    echo $_POST['email'];
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `X-Mailer` in your header like this:

```
$headers = "From: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
```

The X-Mailer header identifies the software that created the e-mail message. I am not pretty sure, may be depending on server php version we need to use this.

Comment: Thank you, however this didn't submit.

Comment: The form is not submitting or the mail is not sending?

Comment: To clarify, the form is NOT submitting.

Comment: When I use the script without the isset, it can send.

Comment: For example: <?php
  $headers = "From: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
 $body = $_POST['name']."\r\n".$_POST['surname']."\r\n".$_POST['message']."\r\n"; 
 mail("xxxx@gmail.com", "New Inquiry", $body, $headers);
 echo $_POST['email'];
?> This will load on page load. But I want to include the variables first.

Comment: When I use a different hosting company, it works fine.

Comment: Black you `action` attribute, then try again. Or, may be this is a silly suggestion, move your php code before your form.

Comment: Did you mean "block?"

Comment: Here's the site...http://www.firstchoicetradesmen.com/yourlocalgasmen/contact

Comment: Change `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` to `action=""`

Comment: Done, but still not working.

Comment: Yeah, may be finally i got it. use `input` instead of `button`. Ex:   <input type="submit" class="your class" name="submit" value="Send Message">

Comment: I wish to chat, but I'm not eligible. I have changed this but with no luck.

Comment: It works fine here amreed8.com/test/contact.php, but not here, firstchoicetradesmen.com/yourlocalgasmen/contact...

Comment: Are you sending the message using `javascript`?

Comment: When i go to development tools in browser and try to send a message. The page is not redirecting but a success message is generating but didn't show.

Comment: Are you getting any email?

Comment: Ok. Thanks, so what should I do?

Comment: I am out of ideas. Even the submit button is not firing.

Comment: I am getting them from the amreed8.com/test/contact.php, but not the other one.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: One last suggestion, try to do this from scratch not using any theme, css or js.

Comment: Ok, it submitted, but I'm waiting for the email.

Comment: Did you used `X-Mailer`?

Comment: I received it. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are most welcome. If you are using `X-Mailer` you can accept my answer.

Comment: Did you downvote my answer? @amreed8

Comment: Nope. I think that it's because this conversation is too long.

Answer (score 0):

your checking for `$_POST['submit']` but not actually sending it.

you need to ass the value yo your submit button:

```
 <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send Message</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, however this didn't work out.